# how to highlight a location on Google Maps Places API

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a simple webpage which shows all subway stations around a particular latitude and longitude. Point A is fixed. Point B is variable (user input). My two goals are:

1. highlight subway stations in the map
2. highlight nearest subway station to point B to reach point A.

Looking up the documentation, I know that a way to do this would be to call: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?types=subway_station&rankby=distance&location=40.7207800,-74.0011190&key=API_KEY

My questions are:

1. This returns json data, how do I display this on a map? (specically on google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP type map)
2. Is there another way to do this?
3. How can I display (or mark) the nearest subway station to point B?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? Specifically paste some code or make a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search

Modify the "types" parameter and play around with the radius :)

Comment: It's useful for my research. If you know how to highlight a building ?